# ValueError: zero-size array to reduction operation minimum which has no identity-Python

Tags: python-2.7

I am trying to calculate the euclidean distance of a satellite imagery. My code works great for small images, but for big images it is failing. I am getting the error and unable to resolve it.
Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "U:\Annoop_WC\Multiband Spectral Anaysis.py", line 139, in <module>
  main()
  File "U:\Annoop_WC\Multiband Spectral Anaysis.py", line 72, in main
  min = np.amin(np.array(ngbh_matrix)[ngbh_matrix != np.amin(ngbh_matrix)])
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py", line 2354, in amin out=out, keepdims=keepdims)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_methods.py",line 14, in _amin
out=out, keepdims=keepdims)
 ValueError: zero-size array to reduction operation minimum which has no identity
```

The code snippet:

```
            if np.amin(ngbh_matrix) == noDataValue:
                min = np.amin(np.array(ngbh_matrix)[ngbh_matrix != np.amin(ngbh_matrix)])
            else:
                min = np.amin(ngbh_matrix)
            if (np.amax(ngbh_matrix)) == noDataValue:
                max = np.amax(np.array(ngbh_matrix)[ngbh_matrix != np.amax(ngbh_matrix)])
            else:
                max = np.amax(ngbh_matrix)
```

Small description on code: I am reading image into arcpy and converting it to numpy array. then it is padded in order to form neighborhood with the nodatavalue. like below Nodatavalue =0. So I have to find min of neighborhood matrix which is not equal to 0.

```
a= |1 2 3 |
   |4 5 6 |
   |7 8 9 |
 neighborhood matrix = |0 0 0|
                       |0 1 2|
                       |0 4 5|
```

Kindly help resolving the error.